# Keep qTip Tool Tip Always Visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2

I am using [qTip2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/) to handle some tool tips on my site. I have the following code inside a template for the pages it applies to:

**HTML**

```
<div class="overview"><a href="#"><img class="border-gray" src="src.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="estimate"><a href="#"><img class="border-gray" src="src.jpg"></a></div>
<!-- More HTML similar to above -->
```

**JS**

```
$('.overview').qtip({
  content: 'Overview',
  position: {
    my: 'bottom center', 
    at: 'top center'
  },
   style: {classes: 'qtip-tipsy'}
});
$('.estimate').qtip({
   content: 'Estimating',
   position: {
     my: 'bottom center', 
  at: 'top center'
  },
   style: {classes: 'qtip-tipsy'}
});
//More JS as above
```

On the individual pages I would like to have the tool tip visible if the class correlates with the page. IE: `site.com/overview` would have the tool tip with the class of `overview` always visible.  As would `site.com/estimate` have the tool tip `estimate` visible.

I have attempted to add this code to the page but it doesn't work:

```
$('.overview').qtip({
   hide: false
});
```

What I am after is when the page loads the tool tip is visible. No mouse over etc is required. The visible tool tip will depend on what page is visible. IE: `/overview` = `.overview` tool tip.

How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE**

The following code will achieve what I am looking for:

```
$('.overview').qtip({
   content: 'Overview',
   position: {
     my: 'bottom center', 
     at: 'top center'
},
  show: {
    ready: true
},
  hide: false,
  style: {classes: 'qtip-tipsy'}
});
```

However this portion of the code is in a template and not editable on the page level:

```
$('.overview').qtip({
  content: 'Overview',
  position: {
    my: 'bottom center', 
    at: 'top center'
  },
   style: {classes: 'qtip-tipsy'}
});
```

If I try this below the above code it doesn't work:

```
$('.overview').qtip({
    show: { ready: true },
    hide: false

});
```

How do I combine the two if one is not editable on the page level? IE: How would I add the `show` and `hide` code into the above code if I cannot edit the code on the page level?

Comment: Uhmm. How about *not* using a tooltip, but rather just showing a `div`?

Comment: @JustinSatyr - For consistency I prefer this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SHOWING BY DEFAULT**

```
$('.overview').qtip({
  content: 'Overview',
  position: {
      my: 'bottom center', 
      at: 'top center'
    },
  style: {classes: 'qtip-tipsy'},
  show: { ready: true }
  });
```

This is the line you need:

```
show: { ready: true }
```

Here is the documentation:
gTip: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/reference/#show
gTip2: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/show/#ready

**SHOWING CONDITIONALLY**

```
<?php
  // Get the url
  $current_url = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
  // Get the two parts of the url, seperated by: /
  $url_array = explode('/', $current_url);
?>

<script>
  $('.overview').qtip({
    content: 'Overview',
    position: {
      my: 'bottom center', 
      at: 'top center'
    },
    /* Check if the second part of the url is 'overview'
       If it is, add the show ready code */
    <?php if( isset( $url_array[1] ) && $url_array[1] == 'overview' ) : ?>
      show: { ready: true },
    <?php endif; ?>
    style: {classes: 'qtip-tipsy'}
  });
</script>
```

**SHOWING CONDITIONALLY | ONLY JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() 
    {
      // Prepare some variables
      var current_url = window.location.host + window.location.pathname;
      var url_array = current_url.split('/');
      // The qtip code
      $('.overview').qtip({
        content: 'Overview',
        position: {
          my: 'bottom center', 
          at: 'top center'
        },
        show: { ready: url_array[1] == overview ? true : false },
        style: {classes: 'qtip-tipsy'}
      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, that is indeed the correct code I need, however, I cannot edit part of the code as I have it in a template on multiple pages. See my update to my question.

Comment: So can you edit the template to add the show: { ready: true }, conditionally as in my updated answer?

Comment: Yes, however, I cannot use php (I am using a hosted CMS). If there is not another way I will drop the template. Extra work to do but not impossible.

Comment: No... Let's try with javascript then. One moment to update the original post. Questions: Isn't there a command to get the overview name? What CMS are you using?

Comment: Business Catalyst is my CMS. I will give the JS a try. Thanks

Comment: No problem! I updated the code again to be better. Please let me know if something is unclear to you and of course if it works or not...

Answer (score -2):

```
 show: {
     ready: true
 },
 hide: {
     event: false
 }
```

Comment: It looks like the Original Poster (OP) has already stated that this is not working for them if they place it after the code.  At the very least this needs some sort of explanation to go with it.